# Navigation menu's first item has strange height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've spent almost an hour trying to get my navigation menu to look nice. 
I'm using Twitter Bootstraps's flat css menu.

For some reason, the first item of the menu has a taller height than every other item in the menu - as seen here:

[image]

How can I get the height of the first item the same as every other list item in the list?

I've tried:

1. Explicitly setting the height of the first list item. Nothing changes.
2. Removing padding from the menu. Nothing changes.
3. Removing margin from the menu. Nothing changes.

[Here's a jsfiddle showing my problem in action](http://jsfiddle.net/hyDLV/). I know the code in the fiddle is a bit messy right now, but I'll work on this later on after I fix this problem.

Code from the fiddle:

HTML:

```
<img id="profile_circle" style="height:25px;width:25px;;border-radius: 16px;float:right;margin-top:10px;border:2px solid #DDD8CE;cursor:pointer;" src="https://secure.gravatar.com/avatar/3ab5cad18247b67090e61f59b47ef7c4?size=20" alt="">

<div style="width:160px;min-height:100px;background-color:white;z-index:3;position:relative;top:40px;left:240px;-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2),inset 0 0 0 #000;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),inset 0 0 0 #000;box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),inset 0 0 0 #000;" class="grey_box">
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li><a href="https://domain.com//profile/jjmpsp">My profile</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://domain.com//universities/">My university</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://domain.com//dumps/">My dumps</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://domain.com//notes/">My notes</a></li>
                                        <li class="divider"></li>
                                        <li><a href="https://domain.com//logout/">Logout</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
```

CSS:

```
.dropdown-toggle:focus{outline:0;}
.dropdown-menu{z-index:1000;display:block;padding:5px 0;list-style:none;font-size:14px;background-color:#ffffff;background-clip:padding-box;margin:0px !important;}
.dropdown-menu .divider{height:1px;margin:9px 0;overflow:hidden;background-color:#e5e5e5;}
.dropdown-menu>li>a{display:block;padding:3px 20px;clear:both;font-weight:normal;line-height:1.428571429;color:#333333;white-space:nowrap;}
.dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>li>a:focus{text-decoration:none;color:#ffffff;background-color:#428bca;}
.dropdown-menu>.active>a,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:hover,.dropdown-menu>.active>a:focus{color:#ffffff;text-decoration:none;outline:0;background-color:#428bca;}

.grey_box {
background-color: #FFF;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
border: 3px solid #DDD8CE;
}
```

Comment: Try putting position: absolute in ur image tag like this .... <img id="profile_circle" style="height:25px;width:25px;;border-radius: 16px;float:right;margin-top:10px;border:2px solid #DDD8CE;cursor:pointer;position:absolute;"..... Keep the image inside div container.

Comment: The menu div could take absolute position, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extra height of the first item comes from your image (profile_circle). This image has set the floating-style (`float:right`). The `div` with your menu inside "floats" besides this image, but the style `.dropdown-menu>li>a` says `block`-layout in addition with `clear:both` for the links in your menu, which places the whole menu "below" the image.

Comment: You were right! I just forgot to add the clearfix. Thank you :)